# ssh-add returns with: "Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

`ssh-add` alone is not working:

```
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```

How should I use that tool?

Comment: Dear moderators, I was ask to moved this question to this site from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997642/ssh-add-command-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment90947452_51997642), but then I got downvote again? Can you at least tell me why?

Comment: I'm guessing you got the downvotes because you fail to explain what your current setup is (with regards to SSH and the SSH agent), and what you may have changed/done when it suddenly no longer worked the way it used to. You also don't mention the command that gives rise to the error message (so we have to assume it's just a plain `ssh-add` with no options).  There is also no reference to the `tmux` tag in the question itself. For more feedback, ask about your question on the [Meta site](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please read our FAQ, take the tour and lurk for a while to get a feel of the forum use.

Comment: Thank you for all the moderators who helped me to improve this questions!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You need to initialize `ssh-agent` first.

You can do this in multiple ways.
Either by starting a new shell

```
ssh-agent bash
```

or by evaluating the script returned by `ssh-agent` in your current shell.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

I suggest using the second method, because you keep all your history and variables.

Comment: Thanks it works for me! Since I'm using `fish`, the command is `ssh-agent fish`.

Comment: that didn't work for me

Comment: I don't want to run additional bash under agent

Comment: what does this do and why is it necessary?

Comment: @WillSheppard It starts a new session with a running `ssh-agent`, which manages your SSH keys.

Answer (score 57):

In Windows PowerShell (run as admin):

1. Check the current status of **ssh-agent**:

   `Get-Service | ?{$_.Name -like '*ssh-agent*'} | select -Property Name, StartType, Status`
2. Enable the Service if it is disabled:

   `Set-Service -Name ssh-agent -StartupType Manual`
3. Start the Service:

   `Start-Service ssh-agent`
4. Add your key as before:

   `ssh-add <path to the key>`

Comment: This is Unix and Linux stack exchange. I'm glad windows users can finally type some good commands at the shell nowadays, but `Get-Service` and alike does nothing for the open source linux community. Maybe a mod can start looking into these type of answers and cut them while we still can, because if we let it flood the forum, we will be doomed in no time.

Comment: @DrBeco there is no "flood" of powershell answers. And, believe it or not, [powershell is actually available on *nix](https://powershellonlinux.com/), so the user of powershell doesn't automatically render an answer off topic. I suspect the commands here won't work on *nix, but since we've also decided that WSL is on topic, and presumably they'd work there, I don't really see much point in removing this answer.

Comment: Thre is no flood "yet". Also, the OP specifically used tag "Linux"

Comment: Well, this was posted three years ago, and the flood has yet to materialize. Dunno, I completely understand what you're saying, this is very unlikely to be an answer to the question as asked (but I am not 100% sure, maybe these commands have been ported and will work as a frontend to `systemctl` or `service` on Linux?). The main point though, is that powershell is available on Linux so its use doesn't make something off topic by definition. And since this has received so many upvotes, I just don't see any benefit in deleting it. Maybe worth opening a discussion on [meta]?

Comment: Thank you! WINDOWS!! YES!

Comment: @DrBeco - It's worth noting that this question (and it's answers) appears prominently in Google search regardless of platform (at least it did for me) - so having an answer address the Windows OS is quite helpful.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Understand that linux users are a minority class compared to windows users. Of course this is a typical case where "majority" of votes are useless, since there is clearly a majority of windows users, and linux would benefit to protect the space while still can. But if the mods are not up for it, who am I to disagree. Let it be. Other unix/linux only spaces in the internet do exist. It is a pitty it is not here at stack exchange, though. (further discussion must be moved to meta / chat - thanks)

Answer (score 35):

The SSH agent is not running, or the environment variables that it sets are not available in the current environment (most importantly `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`), or they are set incorrectly (pointing to a dead agent).

You could start the agent in the current shell session using

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

or start a new shell session through the agent using

```
ssh-agent fish
```

(replace `fish` with whatever shell you are using). But since you say that you *used to* be able to use `ssh-add` without this, it leads me to believe that you've accidentally killed the agent (or it has terminated due to some other reason).  The error message makes me think that the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is actually set, but that `ssh-add` can't find a valid communication socket at that path.

It would not surprise me if your usual way of doing things would work again if you completely logged out and logged in again, or rebooted the machine.

Comment: Yes, I think I killed the agent accidentally, perhaps due to restarting the machine.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed my issue with “Permission denied”

Answer (score 1):

## MacOS

### Big Sur

In my edge case, the problem was I had somehow turned off the service, or it was trying to use bash instead of zsh. Not really sure, but this did the trick:

`ssh-agent zsh`

Comment: That works on zsh!

Answer (score -1):

What I just stumbled uppon is that I couldn't add the key no matter what I tried. Reinstall openssh, start it in systemd, stop, restart, start ssh-agent, kill all ssh-agent processess running and try with a fresh one... I would always end up with that file or directory not found. In the end I removed all SSH keys that I had in my ~/.ssh, created a fresh one that I custom named, and it still didn't work. What **did work** is when I renamed that key to `id_rsa`. For some reason the agent picked that up automatically without the need to add the key to it and started working. Happened on Arch.

Comment: This does not seem to be the issue in this particular question though. Here, the `ssh-add` command can't communicate with the SSH agent.  In your case, the `ssh-add` command could not read your key (possibly due to a permission or ownership issue; you may have used `sudo` to generate the key or to create the `~/.ssh` directory).

Comment: The author stated that "ssh-add alone is not working: Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory", which is a vague question by itself and can be a variety of things and which is also what I experienced. I do not understand how this is a different topic. @Kusalananda

Comment: The error message that is given in the question is exactly what the SSH client says when it can not find the socket file which the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable points to. If the variable is unset (if you never started the agent), `ssh-add` says `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`.