# ssh-add not able to connect to ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, daemon, ssh-agent, protocols

I know that `ssh-add` is "front-end" of `ssh-agent`.

But `ssh-agent` on my computer is already running (I could find it in `top`). When I type `ssh-add`, it said "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent".

How `ssh-add` communicate with `ssh-agent` in details?

My situation is

```
#! /bin/sh

# hello.sh

eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add
```

Then,

```
bash ./hello.sh
```

when I type

```
ssh-add some-new-key
```

in terminal,

It output that error message

Comment: `eval $(ssh-agent)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssh-add returns with: "Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464574/ssh-add-returns-with-error-connecting-to-agent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @Panki, see updated post.

Comment: Your problem is that you are running the script in a new instance of `bash` - source it instead: `source hello.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `ssh-agent -s` is some environment variable assignments, something like `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=blahblah; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK` etc. When you run  `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`, the shell executes that as code, and those variables get set in that shell. The variables there contain the information `ssh-add` needs to contact the agent, and they get inherited down from the shell to the `ssh-add` process.

But here, you're running it from inside `hello.sh`. The shell running the script is an independent process, distinct from the upper interactive shell that started `hello.sh`, and the variables don't get inherited "upwards".

Instead, if you source the script, with `source hello.sh`, or `. hello.sh`, it runs in the *same shell*, and the variables get assigned properly.

Though, if you're running multiple shells (multiple terminal emulators, SSH sessions, screen/tmux windows, whatever), you really only need one `ssh-agent`. You'll have to save the variable assignments to a file somewhere, and load them from e.g. `.bashrc`. But I don't know what exactly you're doing.