# CD using GitLab, Bash script is not working

Tags: bash, gitlab

I am working with [**CI, CD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CI/CD) but unfortunately I messed up with shell scripting. On my gitlab-ci.yml file I called a bashscript at the time on deploy. But unfortunately whenever I want to pull using the command the response is failed. For this bash script my response is

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get server list 
set -f
string=$DEPLOY_SERVER_IP
array=(${string//,/ })

# Iterate servers for deploy and pull last commit 
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "Deploy project on server ${array[i]}"
  ssh bitnami@${array[i]} " ssh-agent bash && ssh-add keys/relation-fe && cd htdocs/relation-fe/ && git pull origin master "
done
```

my response is something like this

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 21206
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ bash .gitlab-deploy-prod.sh
Deploy project on server 1.2.3.4
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

SO how could I solve the error? the error shows that gitlab was successful to access my server but at the time of running the ssh-agent and adding the keys by ssh-key the script cannot execute the commands. Well error comes from here. I'm confused with the bash script and shell script thing. So I cannot figure out the error from my script. I was able to create a file on my git push but I cannot **pull things after authenticating with the ssh-key** can any one help me with this?

Comment: `ssh-agent bash` starts a new shell, you should `eval` the values being returned by it, or pass the identity file directly to `ssh -i`

Comment: [See this post for more info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464574/ssh-add-returns-with-error-connecting-to-agent-no-such-file-or-directory/464579#464579)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But could you please give me an accurate answer by modifying the code?

Comment: Sorry, I got my own work to do :/

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I doubt this is relevant to the issue you describe, but is `[[ -f /.dockerenv ]]` correct? Is that hidden file really supposed to be in the `/` directory? More importantly, does it work if you run the commands manually? Are you sure the problem is the script?

Comment: Have you looked at "[Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17846529/3773011)"?

Comment: @terdon thank you for mentioning that, but I have no docker configuration for my current workbench. as @Panki told that I have some issues on `ssh-agent I'm working with that. Well as far as I think I must have messed up after the ssh command, when I need to add the private key at that time my configuration messed up. I should probably check the bash script that I'm using. If you could understand my problem that It would be much appreciated if you help. Thank you

Comment: @Makyen yap i think i'm somehow messed up at that point. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Gitlab is not connecting to your *runner*, which is different than your server. Make sure that your runner is available and gitlab can connect to it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but there are several ways to do CI and CD. The way you told is to run the gitlab runner on my server so that the runner could trigger the pull request. Well I'm going for a different approach. 
btw thanks for the comment